# How can I select anonymous nested child elements?

Tags: html, css

I have three anonymous children nested in "element-group" and I need to individually change the colour of the rect inside each child element. Unfortunately, I have no way of selecting a specific child element in CSS since each child doesn't have a unique id. This is pre-generated code, and I'm forced to override it using CSS, so I can't simply add a specific id to each element in order to modify each child element separately.

How can I individually select each of the child elements in this grouping in CSS if none of the children have a unique id?

```
<g class="element-group">
   <g class="element">
      <rect class="element-shape bundle-shape" 
         x="101.778125" 
         width="131"
         y="36.44939999999999" 
         height="138.5466" 
         style="fill: rgb(230, 204, 102); 
         stroke-width: 0px; 
         stroke: rgb(0, 128, 128);">
      </rect>
   </g>

   <g class="element">
      ...
   </g>

   <g class="element">
      ...
   </g>
</g>
```

Comment: Define indexing. What do you want to do with the example code you gave?

Comment: Are the classes remains same when its generated ?

Comment: nth-child() ???

Comment: I added more specific details. tldr; I'm trying to individually access child elements that don't have specific ids from CSS, and I can't simply add a unique id to each child because I'm hacking pre-generated code.

Yes, the classes remain the same when it is generated. It generates them all to be the same colour, and I need to use CSS to make them different colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do exactly, but if it's CSS specific you can use the `nth-child` selector:

```
.element:nth-child(2) {...} // replace 2 with whatever index you want.
```

If you're talking about JS then you can use:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('element');
console.log(elements[2]); // replace 2 with whatever index you want.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Apologies for the vague question, I was posting this in a hurry. I've updated details to make the question clearer.